# C# and MS Word , range.font.bold doesn't work

Tags: c#, ms-word

I wand to bold a range on MS Word document using C#.
The code is :

```
Range.Font.Bold=1;
```

When I look at the documnet I see that the bold button is on but the text is not bold.

The same probalem appear when I use Selection method .

Any idea?

Comment: Can you please mark the answer to your question?

Answer (score 16):

I believe it's -1 and not 1

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-ZA/vsto/thread/ec35e23b-22a5-4ffa-95cc-2d5b90d86dd2

```
Range.Font.Bold = -1;
```

Comment: @politrok I would very much appreciate that!

Comment: it's -1 because the value for True in VB is -1